# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros de un formulario en laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

No sé cómo hacer para meter el value de un input como parámetro en una petición a una api, ya que quiero hacer un filtrado y que me muestren solo los productos esos concretamente.

Aquí está mi código:

[image: Como podeis ver es un buscador que aplica un filtro a una api externa]

Rutas:

```
    Route::get('/ropaZappos', function (Request $request) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $datos = $request->busquedaInput; 

    $url = "https://zappos1.p.rapidapi.com/products/list?limit=100&page=1&sort=relevance%2Fdesc&query=$datos"; 
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: zappos1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: b73e3c56bamsh7c33431a69d060dp16ab26jsnc57335704b4f",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ],
    ]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    $todo = null;

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {

        $todo=json_decode($response);
        $ropaArray=$todo->results;
    return view('tienda.zappos', compact('ropaArray', 'datos'));}})->name('ropaZappos');
```

Aquí el html donde viene el campo *busquedaInput* que recogería para el filtrado y también devolvería todos los productos de esa marca, precio, modelo, descripción, etc.

```
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pt-2">
        <div class="col-4 ">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="busquedaInput" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2" >
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" id="button-addon2">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col-xxl-12">

            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach ($ropaArray as $value)
                        <div class="col-md-3 px-4">
                            <!-- EMPIEZA CARD -->
                            <div class="card border card-border-dark text-center" data-aos="flip-right">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid p-1" src=""
                                    alt="">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title mb-2 text-primary">{{ $value->brandName }}</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text mb-0">{{ $value->productName }} </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <p class="card-link link-dark">Color: {{ $value->colorId }} <i
                                            class="ri-bookmark-line align-middle ms-1 lh-1"></i></p>
                                    <h4 class="card-link link-info">Precio: {{ $value->price }}</h4>
                                    <hr>
                                    <a href="{{$value->productUrl}} " target="_blank"> <button type="button"
                                            class="btn btn-success btn-label waves-effect right waves-light rounded-pill">
                                            <i
                                                class=" ri-shopping-cart-2-line  label-icon align-middle rounded-pill fs-16 ms-2"></i>
                                            Comprar</button> </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                      


                        </div> 
                    @endforeach

                </div>
```

No sé si tendré que hacer más rutas o cuál será el fallo.

Comment: Y cómo espera esa api que le pases esos datos? No relacionado, pero laravel ya incluye guzzle como dependencia, y además tiene un [cliente http](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) que es muucho más amigable que curl

Answer (score 0):

consegui arreglarlo, hice un formulario tipo get,

```html
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pt-2">
        <div class="col-4 ">
            <form action="{{ route('ropaZapposBuscador') }}" method="get">
                <label class="form-check-label py-1" > Busqueda en la web</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="busqueda" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2" name="texto" value="{{$texto}}">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

luego hice esta funcion donde la variable texto coje el input texto

```
 public function busca(Request $request)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $texto = trim($request->get('texto'));

    $url = "https://zappos1.p.rapidapi.com/products/list?limit=100&page=1&sort=relevance%2Fdesc&query=$texto";
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host: zappos1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key: b73e3c56bamsh7c33431a69d060dp16ab26jsnc57335704b4f",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ],
    ]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    $todo = null;

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {

        $todo=json_decode($response);
        $ropaArray=$todo;
    return view('tienda.ZapposBuscador', compact('ropaArray', 'texto'));
}
```

}
y por ultimo llamo a la ruta, espero haber ayudado

```
Route::get('/ropaZapposBuscador', [\App\Http\Controllers\Busca::class, 'busca'])->name('ropaZapposBuscador');
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

es en en ningun momento le pasas los valores

```
$post = $request->all();
//$post = [ "datos" => $request->busquedaInput ]

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

aunque si estas en `Laravel` puedes usar esto

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
$response = Http::get('http://example.com');

--------------------------------

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    "X-RapidAPI-Host" => "zappos1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key" => "b73e3c56bamsh7c33431a69d060dp16ab26jsnc57335704b4f",
    "content-type" => "application/json"
])->post("https://zappos1.p.rapidapi.com/products/list?limit=100&page=1&sort=relevance%2Fdesc&query=$datos", $post);
```

pudes leer mas aquí https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client